# How to stop Jupyter Notebook from turning urls into active links?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I recently updated from iPython Notebook 3.x to Jupyter Notebook 4.x and it seems that they changed how urls are handled in code cells.

[Screenshot of how it works now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPWST.png)

Previously, any url within quotes would be treated like any other string. It was marked up in red font and could be edited at will (3rd line in the image). This is how I want it to work again.

Unfortunately, now whenever you have a url (1st line) and you put quotes around it (2nd line) it turns it into an active link for the website. This is infuriating because I can no longer allow me to edit the url because it is being treated as an interact-able object. It even prevents me from modifying the rest of the line of code that the url is a part of. I can't even move the cursor into the line. The cursor just vanishes. To workaround this 'feature' I have to cut and paste the line of code into notepad, edit it, then re-paste it back into the notebook.

I use Google Chrome as my web browser for the notebooks, which is one of the supported browsers according to the website. Could it be that there is a setting in Chrome which is messing things up? Or is it that there is a setting in the Jupyter notebook that I can change to revert the behavior? Or am I just going to have to downgrade to iPython 3.x?